# Remove trailing slash from comment form

Tags: php, trailing-slash

I need code to remove the trailing slash when a user enters their link. For example I need them to put their url to grab their avatar, but in some cases they put their url ending with a slash (.com/). How can I remove that slash automatically? Because when they put their url like that, the avatar doesn't show.

I was looking to remove a trailing slash with php code, but any solution will be appreciated.

I tried to use this code but didn't work:

```
$string = rtrim($string, '/');
```

Comment: In what way did your code not work?

Comment: i tried to put a comment on my website, ending with (.com/) and the code didn't remove the slash, therefore the avatar didn't show.

Comment: Can you paste a five-line program that reproduces the problem?

Comment: static function getProfileImage($screenname, $size = 128) {
        $url = self::API_URL .  $screenname . '/avatar/' . $size;

Comment: if they add another slash at the end of their website, the avatar won't show because the url it's gonna be like this .com//avatar

Comment: For what URL's does your code not work? It works for me: http://codepad.viper-7.com/hvVvLM

Comment: @SergioVargott Then the URL will be invalid. You should have the user fix it instead of assuming what they meant.

Comment: i'm grabbing my commentators avatars from tumblr

Comment: @PhpMyCoder it's now working :/

Answer (score 1):

Use substring(-1). If it equals "/", then remove it

`if (substr($urlString, -1) == "/") $urlString = substr($urlString, 0, -1);`

Comment: thank you, just a question should i put the code inside of the textbox? or in anywhere is fine?

Comment: Just before you store the URL.

Comment: static function getProfileImage($screenname, $size = 128) {
        $url = self::API_URL .  $screenname . '/avatar/' . $size;

Answer (score 0):

The function rtrim just removes whitespace form the end of the string. You should check if the last character in the string is a "/" and then remove it if it is.

One way to do this would be:

```
if (substr_compare($string, "/", -1) == 0) { 
    $string = substr($string, 0, -1);
}
```

Comment: i'm having the same issue, should i put it in the plug in? or in the text box? this is the plug in..     static function getProfileImage($screenname, $size = 128) {
        $url = self::API_URL .  $screenname . '/avatar/' . $size;

Comment: and the text box is another page <input type="textbox" id="ta_tumblr_field" class="textbox" tabindex="4" size="30" name="ta_tumblr_field" value="<?php echo esc_attr($_COOKIE['comment_author_tumblr' . COOKIEHASH]); ?>" />

Comment: Incorrect. `rtrim()` accepts a second option argument `$charList` that takes a string of chars that it should trim from the right of the string along with whitespace.